# #Error in `[.default`(prefix_ad, hits) : invalid subscript type 'S4'

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to run this code # Methylation data:

```
prefix_ad <- data.frame(
Chromosome = c("Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12"),
start = c(91, 153, 244, 249, 257, 259, 284, 298, 312, 1645),
end = c(91, 153, 244, 249, 257, 259, 284, 298, 312, 1645),
count = c(10, 20, 0, 11, 1, 15, 2, 5, 9, 8)
)

# Gene annotations
annotation <- data.frame(
Chromosome = c("Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12", "Ecoli_K12"),
start = c(50, 210, 400),
end = c(200, 350, 600),
gene = c("gene_1", "gene_2", "gene_3")
 )

library(GenomicRanges)
library(dplyr)

# Create GRanges objects for methylation data and gene annotations
gr_methylation <- GRanges(
seqnames = prefix_ad$Chromosome,
ranges = IRanges(start = prefix_ad$start, end = prefix_ad$end)
 )

gr_genes <- GRanges(
seqnames = annotation$Chromosome,
ranges = IRanges(start = annotation$start, end = annotation$end),
id = annotation$gene)

# Match CpG sites to genes
hits <- findOverlaps(gr_methylation, gr_genes)

# Extract the overlapping data
methylation_within_genes <- prefix_ad[hits]

methylated_counts <- tapply(methylation_within_genes$count, methylation_within_genes$, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I want output something like this:

```
chromosome  gene start    end methylated_count
  
Ecoli_K12 gene_1    50    200               30
Ecoli_K12 gene_2   210    350               34
```

I have two questions:

1. is what I am doing correct? Or are there any alternative solutions I need to use?
2. What is causing this error?

> `methylation_within_genes <- prefix_ad[hits]`
> Error in `[.default`(prefix_ad, hits) : invalid subscript type 'S4'

Answer (score 0):

Your `hits` object is nothing that you can directly use for a subsetting operation, here to subset `prefix_ad`. This is what the error is telling you (admittedly in a most unhelpful way). The `hits` contains information of the overlaps between the two inputs, called `from` and `to`. You will see that when you print `hits` to the console. You can access the values with `from()` and `to()` and then use the output for the subsetting, for example:

```r
prefix_ad[from(hits),]
prefix_ad[to(hits),]
```